# Haskell not using the more specific instance of a typeclass

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass, extensibility

I've been having trouble the past few days figuring out whether something I'm trying to do is actually feasible in Haskell.

Here is some context:
I am trying to code a little markup language (akin to ReST) where the syntax already enables custom extensions through *directives*.
For users to implement new directives, they should be able to add new semantic constructs inside the document datatype. For exemple if one wants to add a directive for displaying math, they might want to have a `MathBlock String` constructor inside the ast.

Obviously data types are not extensible, and a solution where there is a generic constructor `DirectiveBlock String` containing the name of the directive (here, `"math"`) is undesirable as we would like to have in our ast only well-formed constructs (so only directives with well-formed arguments).

Using type families, I prototyped something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

-- Arguments for custom directives.
data family Args :: * -> *

data DocumentBlock
    = Paragraph String
    | forall a. Block (Args a)
```

Sure enough, if someone wishes to define a new directive for math display, they can do it as such:

```
data Math
-- The expected arguments for the math directive.
data instance Args Math = MathArgs String

doc :: [DocumentBlock]
doc =
    [ Paragraph "some text"
    , Block (MathArgs "x_{n+1} = x_{n} + 3")
    ]
```

So far so good, we can only construct documents where directive blocks receive the correct arguments.

The problem arises when one user wants to convert the internal representation of a document to some custom output, say, String.
The user needs to provide **a default output for all directives**, since there will be many and some of them cannot be converted to the target.
Furthermore, the user may wish to provide **a more specific output for some directives**:

```
class StringWriter a where
    write :: Args a -> String

-- User defined generic conversion for all directives.
instance StringWriter a where
   write _ = "Directive"

-- Custom way of showing the math directive.
instance StringWriter Math where
    write (MathArgs raw) = "Math(" ++ raw ++ ")"

-- Then to display a DocumentBlock
writeBlock :: DocumentBlock -> String
writeBlock (Paragraph t) = "Paragraph(" ++ t ++ ")"
writeBlock (Block args)  = write args

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ writeBlock (Block (MathArgs "a + b"))
```

With this example, the output is `Block` and not `Math(a+b)`, so the generic instance for StringWriter is always chosen. Even when playing with `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}`, nothing succeeds.

Is the kind of behavior I'm describing possible at all in Haskell?

---

When trying to include a generic Writer inside the `Block` definition, it also fails to compile.

```
-- ...

class Writer a o where
    write :: Args a -> o

data DocumentBlock
    = Paragraph String
    | forall a o. Writer a o => Block (Args a)

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Writer a String where
   write _ = "Directive"

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Writer Math String where
    write (MathArgs raw) = "Math(" ++ raw ++ ")"

-- ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile, since `Block something` has type `DocumentBlock`, while `write` expects an `Args a` argument, and the two types are different.
Did you mean `writeBlock` instead? I'll assume so.

What you might want to try is to add a constraint in your existential type, e.g.:

```
data DocumentBlock
    = Paragraph String
    | forall a. StringWriter a => Block (Args a)
             -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --
```

This has the following effect. Operationally, every time `Block something` is used, the instance is remembered (a pointer is implicitly stored along the `Args a` value). That will be a pointer to the catch-all instance, or to the specific one, whichever is the best fit.

When the constructor is then pattern-matched later on, the instance can then be used. Full working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

-- Arguments for custom directives.
data family Args :: * -> *

data DocumentBlock
    = Paragraph String
    | forall a. StringWriter a => Block (Args a)

data Math
-- The expected arguments for the math directive.
data instance Args Math = MathArgs String

doc :: [DocumentBlock]
doc =
    [ Paragraph "some text"
    , Block (MathArgs "x_{n+1} = x_{n} + 3")
    ]

class StringWriter a where
    write :: Args a -> String

-- User defined generic conversion for all directives.
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} StringWriter a where
   write _ = "Directive"

-- Custom way of showing the math directive.
instance StringWriter Math where
    write (MathArgs raw) = "Math(" ++ raw ++ ")"

-- Then to display a DocumentBlock
writeBlock :: DocumentBlock -> String
writeBlock (Paragraph t) = "Paragraph(" ++ t ++ ")"
writeBlock (Block args)  = write args

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ writeBlock (Block (MathArgs "a + b"))
```

This prints `Math(a + b)`.

A final note: for this to work it is crucial that all the relevant instances are in scope when `Block` is used. Otherwise, GHC might choose the wrong instance, causing some unintended output. This is the main limitation, making overlapping instances a bit fragile in general.
As long as there are no orphan instances, this should work.

Also note that, if using other existential types, a user can (intentionally or accidentally) cause GHC to pick the wrong instance anyway. For instance, if we use

```
data SomeArgs = forall a. SomeArgs (Args a)

toGenericInstance :: DocumentBlock -> DocumentBlock
toGenericInstance (Block a) = case SomeArgs a of
   SomeArgs a' -> Block a'  -- this will always pick the generic instance
toGenericInstance db = db
```

then, `writeBlock (toGenericInstance (Block (MathArgs "a + b")))`
will produce `Directive` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and sorry about the typo, you assumed right and I just fixed it.

I did have a similar solution at some point, however it does not suit the scope of what I am trying to do: provide a generic document model and let users define conversion to some other target language. We have to assume that `StringWriter a` is not available when defining the `DocumentBlock`.

When trying to define a more generic typeclass `Writer a o` that will be refined by users, it fails to compile, as directives will not implicetly have an instance for any `Writer a o`.
(See next comment)

Comment: (I have no idea how SO works so see the original post for the code example)

Comment: @flupe As long as you also provide a generic catch-all instance `instance Writer a o` to be overlapped by users, the constraints should not be a problem, since they can always be satisfied. It is important, though, that the specific instances are in scope when they have to be used.

Comment: @flupe Actually, that constraint is way too weak: it only requires a conversion to "some `o`", which will be useless later on since we can't rely on any `o`. You need a fixed return type for `write`, or something similar.